# Inserting some 200 records in orientDB

Tags: orientdb

I want to insert 200 records in a class(table).

Using this query to insert these different kind of values.

I want to know if there is any alternative method to insert data in a table?

I have 300 records to insert to orientdb database

My query:

```
insert into PARAMETER_FUNCTION (module_name,label,key,info_type,order)
values ('Payroll', 'Associate Deduction To Deduction Sub Category',125,'TDS_centra**l',4)
```

Comment: If you want insert a vertex you can use http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-Create-Vertex.html

Comment: In that vertex can i insert my 300 records at a time?

Comment: The rows are unique in all the 300 rows.Can i insert it like that?

Comment: Is gremlin will be usefull for inserting these many bulk data?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
insert into Person (name) values ('John'),('Michael'),('Bruce')
```

**EDIT**

```
insert into Person (name,surname,age) values ('John','Terry',32),('Michael','Jordan',53)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: your answer holds good for single data..I have bulk data.The rows are arround 400 plus..I can not go on using insert statements for all 400 rows..i need an some other solutions.  For example:- In MS Sql,if we have bulk data means we will put it into excel sheet ,then we will convert that data into required form... and we will import it to database directly..Is there any solutions   ij orient db for bulk data?

Comment: you'r query would be useful only if we have one column,i have 5 columns of different name,at that how can i use this query to insert data.

Comment: There is no other way other than insert statement?